# Django error "TemplateDoesNotExist" despite template existing

Tags: python, django, django-templates, cs50

Trying to go through the cs50 web programming course and I've been stupidly stuck on one issue.
I'm trying to render an entry template page if a title exists as defined by a get_entry variable and an error template if not.

The branch:

```
encyclopedia
|-- templates
  |-- encyclopedia
     |-- error.html
     |-- entry.html
|-- views.py
|-- urls.py
```

```
def entry(request, title):
    page = util.get_entry(title),
    if page == None:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html")
    else:
        return render(request, "encylopedia/entry.html")
```

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/wiki/css

Django Version: 4.2.4
Python Version: 3.11.4
Installed Applications:
['encyclopedia',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Template loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/kajakubickova/cs50/wiki/encyclopedia/templates/encylopedia/entry.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/encylopedia/entry.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/encylopedia/entry.html (Source does not exist)



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/kajakubickova/cs50/wiki/encyclopedia/views.py", line 16, in entry
    return render(request, "encylopedia/entry.html")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 24, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 19, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /wiki/css
Exception Value: encylopedia/entry.html
```

I've been trying to change around the urls, watched some wiki explanations, but honestly I'm a django beginner and I'm a bit last as to where the error is.

Comment: Can you show how the `TEMPLATES` setting looks like in your `settings.py` ?

Comment: what did you put in urls.py and what did you hit on browser? what path